# How can I create a python3 venv in cmake install?

Tags: python, cmake, python-venv

I have a medium sized project composed by many parts, mostly in C++, but testing and configuration relies on Python3 scripts.

The project buildsystem is generated using CMake and installed (by CMake rules) in a "deploy" directory.

I would like to create a Python venv to segregate changes.
I have the following CMake fragment:

```
set(VENV ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/venv)
set(REQUIREMENTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/testing/scripts/requirements.txt)
set(BIN_DIR ${VENV}/bin)
set(PYTHON ${BIN_DIR}/python)
set(OUTPUT_FILE ${VENV}/environment.txt)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_FILE}
    COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} -m venv ${VENV}
    COMMAND ${BIN_DIR}/pip install -U pip wheel
    COMMAND ${BIN_DIR}/pip install -r ${REQUIREMENTS}
    COMMAND ${BIN_DIR}/pip freeze > ${VENV}/environment.txt
    DEPENDS ${REQUIREMENTS}
)
add_custom_target(venv DEPENDS ${PYTHON})
```

... but I don't know how to trigger the `venv` target while doing installation.

I am unsure if this is the right approach (comments welcome, of course), but need should be quite clear: I need to be able to run my scripts from the "deploy" directory using something like:

```
venv/bin/python test-script.py
```

or use a custom: `#!venv/bin/python` line (I am working under Linux).

### UPDATE:

My somewhat working code, based on @user Answer, is as follows:

```
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter)
set(VENV "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/venv")
set(REQUIREMENTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/testing/scripts/requirements.txt")
set(BIN_DIR "${VENV}/bin")
install(CODE "
      MESSAGE(\"Creating VENV from ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} to ${VENV}\")
      execute_process(COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} -m venv ${VENV} )
      execute_process(COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT COMMAND ${BIN_DIR}/pip install -U pip wheel )
      execute_process(COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT COMMAND ${BIN_DIR}/pip install -r ${REQUIREMENTS} )
")
```

Equivalent code with `set(...` and `find_package(...` inside `install(CODE...` did not work; also quoting seems wrong.

I will accept this answer, but I would like to clarify the above.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [`install(SCRIPT ...)` or `install(CODE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#custom-installation-logic)?

Comment: @user: it may be (`install(CODE...` looks promising), but documentation is very terse and I am unsure how to use it. If you can provide an answer with some example code... Please note I am **not** a `cmake` expert, by far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [`install(SCRIPT)` or `install(CODE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#custom-installation-logic):

> The `SCRIPT` form will invoke the given CMake script files during installation. If the script file name is a relative path it will be interpreted with respect to the current source directory. The `CODE` form will invoke the given CMake code during installation. Code is specified as a single argument inside a double-quoted string.

I believe it would be done something like this (using the `CODE` form here to make it easier to do variable substitution and use some of the variables that wouldn't be available outside the context of the configuration phase (i.e. if you were to use the `SCRIPT` mode) without explicitly passing them):

```
install(CODE "
    set(VENV \"\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/venv\")
    set(REQUIREMENTS \"${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/testing/scripts/requirements.txt\")
    set(BIN_DIR \"${VENV}/bin\")
    set(OUTPUT_FILE \"${VENV}/environment.txt\")
    execute_process(COMMAND \"${Python3_EXECUTABLE}\" -m venv \"${VENV}\")
    execute_process(COMMAND \"${BIN_DIR}/pip\" install -U pip wheel)
    execute_process(COMMAND \"${BIN_DIR}/pip\" install -r \"${REQUIREMENTS}\")
    execute_process(COMMAND \"${BIN_DIR}/pip\" freeze > \"${VENV}/environment.txt\")
    execute_process(COMMAND \"${REQUIREMENTS}\")
")
```

See also [the docs for `execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) if you want to do things like handle command failures, etc.